# Arrays in Haxe with multiple types

Tags: haxe

In Javascript, it's possible to create an array with nested arrays inside it, in a single line of code. Is it possible to do the equivalent in Haxe?

```
var a = [
    ["This is a nested array"],
    ["This is another nested array"],
    "This is not a nested array"
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly the same syntax in this case and `a` should be typed as `Array<Dynamic>`.

Comment: I'm surprised haxe can't do multiple types, e.g. with the Flow type system for javascript you can do `var myParam:string|number = "a string or a number"`

Answer (score 0):

One other approach for handling mixed-type arrays is to use enums.  This will change the run time values, but give the compiler a way to define and handle the types that the array could contain.

https://haxe.org/manual/types-enum-using.html

This approach won't work if you can't control how the arrays are being filled.